# boolean algebra - belnap logic

Tags: abstract-algebra, boolean-algebra

How to find out wether an algebra is a correct boolean algebra? So if we have the following algebra (rejects to belnap-logic theorems): 
$ \langle \{ w,f, \top , \bot \} , \wedge  \vee \neg \rangle$